# XML Doctypedefinition (+,*,-) Identifyers in <!Element>

Tags: xml, dtd

Hey guys I'm trying to get into XML but I found something I dont really understand. Let's say I've got a Doctypedefinition like this :

```
   <!Doctype Game
   <!Element Player (Name+,Race*)>
   .
   .
   . and so on
```

What do the + and * signs mean that are written behind the Element Declarations in ?

Comment: First, note that the keywords in a DTD must be upper-case (e.g ELEMENT). Secondly, where did you look? You shouldn't be asking here for information that can be found in any XML textbook or tutorial. Downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+`, `*`, and `?` are occurrence indicators.

`+` = one or more (at least one)

`*` = zero or more

`?` = zero or one

There is no `-` in an XML element declaration. It is used in SGML element declarations to specify tag minimization and exclusions, but you shouldn’t need to worry about those with XML.

So in your example:

```
<!ELEMENT Player (Name+,Race*)>
```

The element `Player` must contain at least one `Name` element followed by (that’s what the comma means) zero or more `Race` elements.

Check out the [quick ref from Mulberry Technologies](https://www.mulberrytech.com/quickref/XMLquickref.pdf). It does a good job of breaking it down.